# PyGTK support ended

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, pygtk

I have some Python experience and I want to start learning GUI development with Python. Latest stable release for GTK+ is from 4 months ago, but latest stable release for PyGTK is 3 years old. Is this a bad sign? Does this mean that there is no support anymore for PyGTK? Are there any information (not opinon-based) about future of PyGTK?

Comment: From the PyGTK website: "New users are encouraged to use GTK+3 through the [PyGObject](https://live.gnome.org/PyGObject) bindings instead of using PyGTK". These seem to be actively maintained.

Comment: All the information about PyGObject can be found at the gnome wiki dedicated page: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/PyGObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gtk+2 was being used with PyGTK. Newer is Gtk+3 and you can use it with PyGObject. Take a look at note on [official PyGTK webpage](http://www.pygtk.org/):

> Note: New users are encouraged to use GTK+3 through the PyGObject bindings instead of using PyGTK with GTK+2. Windows users may still want to keep using PyGTK until more convenient installers are published.